# NSXMLParsing data, retriving data problem during parsing

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

i am creating an app in which i want to take xmldata using webservices.
i am using NSXMLParser.
i get the data in respond data when this below method calling
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    //NSLog(@"====== Connection ========");
    [catalogData appendData:data];
    //NSLog(@"catalog data-=-=-=-=-=-=-%@", catalogData);
}

but when i parse this catalogData in finishloading method i get the null array.
i don't know what the problem is,

this is my XML data

3
      1
      
      
      1

```
  <sPagRichiestaFornitore>
  </sPagRichiestaFornitore>
  <idCategoria>1</idCategoria>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSLog your data inside connectionfinishloading then. If you get a proper XML, then you can create the XML parser accordingly.

You can refer the [Top Paid Sample app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TopPaid/Introduction/Intro.html) of apple for the NSXMLParser Implementation.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply...  i get the data in my connectionFinishloading methods but i get the earning like    Class "CatalogParser" does not implement NSXmlParserDelegateprotocol. i think it should might be create problem for parsing data.

Comment: seems you missed to implement some of the NSXMLParser delegate methods. Better you should refer the sample code. You will get a better understanding.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html check this refrence also.

Answer (score 0):

i cannot help with such a small code friend . can you please tell what exactly you get in response if you not getting please check your php file that is on server some problem with that . One thing i suggest you is that  once remove this tag from your php file and again try to get response

thanks
hope this helps

Comment: i get the response code as a cataloData. i am also print in NSLog but i think my parser had some mistake. i get the warning like Class "CatalogParser" does not implement NSXmlParserDelegateprotocol.

Comment: then you add delegate in .h file <nsxmlparserdelegate>